# Extend existing class and add clone() method C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have an existing vendor supplied class MyClass() that I cannot modify and I want to add a clone method to it.  I thought the following would do it, but the MemberwiseClone() method isn't being found by the obj.

```
public static class MyExtensions 
{
    public static MyClass Clone(this MyCLass obj)
    {
        return (MyClass) obj.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: instead of using MemberWiseClone why not returning a new member with the same data?

Comment: @Lior, because he doesn't have access to the class. Which means he doesn't have access to its internal state.

Comment: well, if it is serializable he can always serialize it and deserialize it as new object..

Comment: @Lior lol you read my mind, I just added that to my post ;)

Comment: yeah I just read it :) didn't see your edit before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because [`MemberwiseClone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a protected method, and is not accessible from `MyExtensions`.

The only way for you to perform this, is if `MyClass` is not marked as sealed. In that case, you can subclass it and use that type instead of the one provided by the vendor.

Please note that `MemberwiseClone` performs a *shallow copy*. Value type members are re-created entirely, but reference type members are not. The clone and the original object will be pointing to the same object.

If you cannot subclass `MyClass`, reconsider your need for a cloning method.
If you *really* do need it, I see two possible options, none of which are advisable: using reflection to copy all fields or serializing/deserializing an instance (if the type supports serialization).

Comment: Thank you for the conversation all.  So, the vendor did not add add Serializable to the object, so I'm assuming that that serialization is not an option.  Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Well, that just means you can't use `BinaryFormatter`. You can use other serializers. Give [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) a shot.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to C# so I still have a lot to learn.  In other languages you can specify when you pass a variable whether it is by reference or by value.  I gather in C# (maybe even OOP) that this is not possible with objects?

Comment: That's a complex question, and everyone seems to have his own definition of "pass by ref/value". But the basics are: In C# you have value types (structs) and reference types. When you call a method and pass a value type, a bit-by-bit copy is performed. When you pass a reference type instance, the reference (or pointer) is copied. I suggest you google "value types and reference types". After that, you might want to learn about the `ref`/`out` keywords while you're at it.

Comment: Great, thank you for the suggestions and help.  I'll do more homework on what you suggested.